Is there any source that says a person should have kaf zechut to anothers shechita
I know a person who is machmir on not eating meat from others he said only if he does the shechita himself he will trust to eat it. Is there any law that mandates others to trust in others people shechita?

There is a law that an expert schochet is trusted even when he works alone, see Mishne Torah Hilchot Shechita 4:4. We don't trust anyone but we do trust certified experts. Today there are supervisors that check the schechita and we rely on them

The smach details 3 different ways to verify the shechita. 1. Check the shochets knife 2. Rely on the rav of the town to check the shochets for you 3. He personally knows the shochet and knows that he is a G-d fearing jew

@Moishe , are you referring to the Simla Chadasha ?

@sam yes the general shorthand term for simla Chadasha Is smach
